# Spring instantiate prototype beans by manual call

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, dependency-injection

I have a `@Configuration` class that I try to use for the sake of custom configuration of JMS components of my application. Here it's simplified code:

```
@Configuration
class JmsConfiguration(
    val props: JmsProperties
) : JmsListenerConfigurer {
    @Bean
    fun connectionFactoryManager(): ConnectionFactoryManager {
        return ConnectionFactoryManager(props.services.map { serviceProps ->
            connectionFactory(serviceProps)
        }.toList())
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    fun connectionFactory(serviceProps: JmsServiceProps): ConnectionFactory {
        val cf = MQConnectionFactory()
        // some configuration
        return cf
    }

    override fun configureJmsListeners(registrar: JmsListenerEnpointRegistrar) {
        // adding custom message listeners to registrar
    } 
}
```

The thing is that Spring complains about `connectionFactory` method and it's parameter `serviceProps` saying the following: "Parameter 0 of method `connectionFactory` in `JmsConfiguration` required a bean of type `JmsServiceProps` that could not be found" which is pretty strange. I thought that spring doen't lookup parameters for `prototype` scoped bean factory methods? If this is not the case and I'm wrond how should I create such instances?

Note: I need these connection factories to be present in spring context since they are being wrapped by other components thereafter.

Comment: I guess `@Configuration @EnableConfigurationProperties(JmsServiceProps.class)`?

Comment: @Eugene yeah, you're right, I just missed that, the problem is not that my properties are not getting read. Spring for some reason tries to find `serviceProps` in context while I call this method manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that properties file is a `@Bean`, you need tell Spring about it. The simplest way is to do :

```
@Configuration 
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JmsServiceProps.class)
```

Comment: yeah, you're right, I just missed that, the problem is not that my properties are not getting read. Spring for some reason tries to find `serviceProps` in context while I call this method manually.

Comment: I just answered the question you had on "Parameter 0 of method connectionFactory in JmsConfiguration required a bean of type JmsServiceProps". Is there a _different_ question you currently have, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Nope, I mean I call `connectionFactory` from within `connectionFactoryManager` and provide parameter for this prototype scoped method manually. Why spring tries to find parameters for this automatically, is this how it is working for prototype beans?

Comment: @mr.nothing I guess for Spring, `serviceProps` that you pass is not a bean, as the message says : "required **a bean** of type JmsServiceProps". And where did you get "I thought that spring doen't lookup parameters for prototype scoped bean factory methods?" this part? is this documented?

Comment: But otherwise this doesn't make any sense. What is the usecase of `PROTOTYPE` scope then? AFAIU it is espcially introduced to make some type of parametrization during bean instantiation.

Comment: @mr.nothing you might want to document yourself then, cause your understanding is not correct. Neither your usage with passing `serviceProps` explicitly (without this being a Spring managed bean) is correct.